# Mod Rewrite rules for redirecting a single subdirectory and its contents

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following folder structure:

```
/
/backend + sub-pages (these are the ones I want to hide)
/backend/admin + sub-pages
/backend/api + sub-pages
```

At the moment, the CMS generates a whole load of pages under the folder `/backend`, which I don't want to be visible to the public.

I require that any route `/backend/*` *except for any route in the `/backend/admin` sub-folder or `backend/api` sub-folder*, is redirected to `/backend`.

Is this possible using mod rewrite in an htaccess file?

Comment: Do you already have rules in .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that mod_rewrite is properly enabled, you can use the following rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/(admin|api)
RewriteRule ^backend/. /backend [R,L]
```

The condition prevents anything from happening if admin or api is behind 'backend'. Otherwise any url that starts with backend/ and at least a single character following that will be redirected to `backend`. This is mainly to prevent redirect loops. Once you have tested this, and it works as you expect, you can change `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]` to make the redirect permanent.